# add td element to tr with id

Tags: javascript, html

Pretty much what the title says. I have html documnet with

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

setup and want a javascript function to add `<td id="2"></td>` under the previous one so it looks like.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1"></td>
    <td id="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use of integers as `ID` is ill advise, 
start with a letter from [A-Za-z] and followed by number or other characters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

javascript(Pure) [`insertCell()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp) method used for Insert new cell(s) into a table row.

Insert new cell(s) with content at the end of a table row using insertCell():

```
var row = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
var x = row.insertCell(-1);
x.innerHTML="New cell";
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKgw9/4/)

You can also use Javascript [`.appendChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp):

```
var parenttbl = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var newel = document.createElement('td');
var elementid = document.getElementsByTagName("td").length
newel.setAttribute('id',elementid);
newel.innerHTML = "New Inserted"
parenttbl[0].appendChild(newel);
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKgw9/2/)

**Updated:**

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr id="myrow">
    <td id="1">Hello</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="1">Hello</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="1">Hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var parenttbl = document.getElementById("myrow");
var newel = document.createElement('td');
var elementid = document.getElementsByTagName("td").length
newel.setAttribute('id',elementid);
newel.innerHTML = "New Inserted"
parenttbl.appendChild(newel);
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKgw9/6/)

Comment: I think that isn't good idea to works by indexes. What if he has one row above the this with indexes? Or if he doesn't know in which row is td with ID?
The better way is to use td's ID, to get parent element (tr) and there to add new td.

Comment: yes, you are right but here i only cover-up OP requirements. Please see updated answer..)

Comment: @IshanJain, I have response from ajax as <td>, can we add to tr?

Answer (score 6):

use jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#1').parent().append('<td id="2">2</td>');

});
```

Answer (score 4):

no need to use jQuery for such a simple thing,do this:

```
var tbl = document.querySelector("table");
var row0 = tbl.rows[0];
```

or

```
var row0 = document.querySelector("#1");
```

then insert your cell:

```
var cell1=row0.insertCell(1);//the 1 here is the cell index
cell1.id="2";
```

to manage DOM elements, I usually offer to code with native JavaScript, instead of using jQuery or any other JavaScript frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery `.append()` method...

```
$('tr').append('<td>content</td>').attr('id', '2');
```

Demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitlamba009/THhNY/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addField () {

        var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;

        var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

        var a ;
        var currentCell= currentRow.insertCell(-1);
        currentCell.style.height="25px";
        currentCell.style.width="20px";
        globalCheck=globalCheck+1;
        currentCell.innerHTML="<input id=\"check"+globalCheck+"\" type=\"checkbox\"></input>";
```

Comment: Don't post code only. Especially _this_ much. Try to focus your answer on the bare minimum.