# HTML shorten repeated code of empty table

Tags: html, sqlite, html-table

I have a table and I fill it up with empty columns and use ajax to update that data in real time. I don't have any data initially in them so it just looks like `<td></td>` 21 times. Here is what it a portion of the table looks like:

```
<table>
<tr class = "fff">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I update the data using binding or something with a timer and this code changes the specific td:

```
$("#fff td:nth-child(2)").html(Math.random() * 100);
```

I tried using nth-child(9) without creating 9 's but it doesn't work. Is there some way I can update the tables without having a bunch of empty td brackets?

Essentially I want to load data from a small SQLite database into the table, and that SQLite database will be updated externally so it's always the same size and the html table will have the same information visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `tr` needs updating, not the specific `td` - right? You need to add a new `<td>data</td>` into the `tr` dynamically using Javascript for each row of data from your database, where you start with an empty `<tr></tr>` - I assume. If so, then try this:

The following code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106943/add-td-element-to-tr-with-id)

```
function insert(){
   var row = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
   var x = row.insertCell(1);
   var elementid = document.getElementsByTagName("td").length
   /* x.setAttribute('id',elementid); Not needed in your case */
   x.innerHTML="New cell";
}
```

You could update the line `var row` to find a `tr` with a specific ID if you prefer to a unique ID for it in your HTML. You would repeat this for every new row of data. `x.innerHTML` of course would contain the data you are querying from your database.